# Login with OAuth2 And Azure Active Directory With Personal account microsoft

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, oauth, azure-active-directory

Hello guys i have exactly the same problem in this question:
[Login with personal Microsoft accounts failes to Oauth2 v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57712737/login-with-personal-microsoft-accounts-failes-to-oauth2-v2)

But i don't understand the answer, where i should configure this link in the manifest? https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize

My manifest is:

```
{
"id": "0982f18d-116c-45c0-b1ee-59dd9fa3344b",
"acceptMappedClaims": null,
"accessTokenAcceptedVersion": 2,
"addIns": [],
"allowPublicClient": null,
"appId": "002543f2-87b6-43e4-91a3-cfdef655dc7a",
"appRoles": [],
"oauth2AllowUrlPathMatching": false,
"createdDateTime": "2021-02-04T10:09:11Z",
"disabledByMicrosoftStatus": null,
"groupMembershipClaims": null,
"identifierUris": [],
"informationalUrls": {
    "termsOfService": null,
    "support": null,
    "privacy": null,
    "marketing": null
},
"keyCredentials": [],
"knownClientApplications": [],
"logoUrl": null,
"logoutUrl": null,
"name": "AppBotTipBook",
"oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow": false,
"oauth2AllowImplicitFlow": false,
"oauth2Permissions": [],
"oauth2RequirePostResponse": false,
"optionalClaims": null,
"orgRestrictions": [],
"parentalControlSettings": {
    "countriesBlockedForMinors": [],
    "legalAgeGroupRule": "Allow"
},
"passwordCredentials": [
    {
        "customKeyIdentifier": null,
        "endDate": "2299-12-30T23:00:00Z",
        "keyId": "86c3141b-02ac-4d47-9ecf-0cabb8ba2fc4",
        "startDate": "2021-02-04T10:10:43.464Z",
        "value": null,
        "createdOn": "2021-02-04T10:10:44.3986206Z",
        "hint": "_3D",
        "displayName": "botlogin"
    }
],
"preAuthorizedApplications": [],
"publisherDomain": "unisalerno.onmicrosoft.com",
"replyUrlsWithType": [
    {
        "url": "https://token.botframework.com/.auth/web/redirect",
        "type": "Web"
    }
],
"requiredResourceAccess": [
    {
        "resourceAppId": "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
        "resourceAccess": [
            {
                "id": "570282fd-fa5c-430d-a7fd-fc8dc98a9dca",
                "type": "Scope"
            },
            {
                "id": "e1fe6dd8-ba31-4d61-89e7-88639da4683d",
                "type": "Scope"
            },
            {
                "id": "b340eb25-3456-403f-be2f-af7a0d370277",
                "type": "Scope"
            },
            {
                "id": "e383f46e-2787-4529-855e-0e479a3ffac0",
                "type": "Scope"
            },
            {
                "id": "37f7f235-527c-4136-accd-4a02d197296e",
                "type": "Scope"
            },
            {
                "id": "14dad69e-099b-42c9-810b-d002981feec1",
                "type": "Scope"
            }
        ]
    }
],
"samlMetadataUrl": null,
"signInUrl": null,
"signInAudience": "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount",
"tags": [],
"tokenEncryptionKeyId": null
```

}

For now the authentication works only for my university domain, but i want to allow the authentication through microsoft personal email, like xxxx@hotmail.com

Comment: The answer you linked answers the question. You need to modify the authorization URL your app uses. This is not in the manifest. It is in your app configuration/code.

Comment: Can you be more specific? with an example image? or something like that

Comment: @juunas i tried this one but i can't update with "Common" i can't write in this string https://pasteboard.co/JNo82VS.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code developed you would be using an endpoint to authorize and get the oauth token.

If you are using MSAL (Microsoft Authentication Library)

The commonly used parameters to configure the client app in your code would

Client ID
Redirect URI
Authority
Client Secret in some cases

So in this, you will have to configure authority url.

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-client-application-configuration#authority
```

So for example in your code, if you are building client application object, you would something like below  :

```
string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common";
 string[] scopes = new string[] { "user.read" };
 IPublicClientApplication app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
      .Create(clientId)
      .WithAuthority(authority)
      .Build();
```

**Update :**

1. Go to Bot Channels Registration page ([Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com))
2. Click Setting
3. OAuth Connection Settings -> Add Setting
4. In the new setting pag - enter the connection name, client app related informations in the following page

You will be using this connection name in your code.

Here's the catch :
Under **tenantid**,  fill it up as a **common** rather than a specific tenant id.

Comment: I use the authentication in bot framwork like this:self.add_dialog(
            OAuthPrompt(
                OAuthPrompt.__name__,
                OAuthPromptSettings(
                    connection_name=connection_name,
                    text="Accedi",
                    title="Sign In",
                    timeout=300000,
                ),
            )
        )

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=aadv2%2Ccsharp#azure-ad-v2-1

Comment: You can find the detailed steps in the above article